azure.archive.ubuntu.com missing data. /ubuntu/pool missing, /ubuntu/ubuntu/pool empty
We've got a bunch of worker VMs in Azure that are failing to provision. What appears to be going on is that azure.archive.ubuntu.com isn't working properly and doesn't have everything available.
We're asking the vendor if it's possible to use an alternative sources list to grab from a different location, but in the mean time, is there a way I can report this fault so it can be looked at and fixed? I've tested from multiple machines, both within Azure, our corporate network, and personal machines at home and it appears to be consistent.
Thanks all

The url is fine. You can visit it with your web browser and it shouldn't show up as 404. This means you're dealing with a networking issue on your end. Often, you can simply try a different server and it will work because of many different reasons. But in this case, I would say you need to fix the networking issue on your end.

That is, if you're dealing with the same 404 issue as in the other post.

I don't get a 404, it's not a network issue preventing access.
From multiple endpoints I am able to browse azure.archive.ubuntu.com but the path it needs azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool is non-existent, and it should be there.

I'm mostly just wanting to know what is the best way to get this raised an issue with whoever owns azure.archive.ubuntu.com, I can't find how to open a ticket with Ubuntu, I am in the process of opening a ticket with Azure support (no response yet via a third party that we have to go through).

Seems to be fine: https://i.sstatic.net/QswdN3rn.png (browsed from a home network connection in Japan)

Still not working for me here. https://share.icloud.com/photos/09cDql_rw3RGjkLPHcZ5yhhtA
The DNS record for azure.archive.ubuntu.com is a CNAME that points to Azure traffic manager (ubuntu-archive-asm.trafficmanager.net). Any chance you'd be willing to let me know what IP it resolves to for you? For me resolves to 20.53.66.23. I wonder if it's a local AU based mirror that has the fault only. I have a ticket with MS open, might be useful information to share on the support ticket.

For me, dig azure.archive.ubuntu.com +short => ubuntu-archive-asm.trafficmanager.net. => cloud-mirror-lb.japaneast.cloudapp.azure.com. => 20.194.180.116

Thanks muru, if I browse that IP /ubuntu/pool is available and content is there. Must be a regional outage for Australia, somewhere within Microsoft's infrastructure.
